# Valid line breaks in adverbs "...ly" in US English?

Tags: american-english, hyphens, dictionaries

According to Merriam-Webster and Oxford online dictionaries for AmE, the right way to hyphenate "mathematically" is "math·e·mat·i·cal·ly". However, some style guides for AmE insist on never leaving two letters on the second line alone (e.g., http://www.k12reader.com/punctuation/hyphenation_in_line_breaks.pdf). Applying this rule, the only hyphenation points would be "math·e·mat·i·cally".

Is this a contradiction or do I misunderstand something? What's the general rule for breaking adverbs of the form "...ly"?

Comment: Although I don't know much enough (and too lazy at the moment to search for more information, sorry!) to discuss this in-depth, I'd like to point out that syllabification (especially the orthographic one) and hyphenation (i.e., word breaks), though closely related, are not the same thing.

Comment: This is really a matter of *typographic* convention and not a grammatical issue. In other words, people may just disagree about what is best. Compare this for example with differences between style guides, such as spacing, indentation, justification, and so on. As with all such rules, the most important thing is to be internally consistent within a piece of writing.

Comment: This should be migrated to ELU, like Mark McGregor's previous question about hyphenation.

Comment: We migrated an almost identical question to ELU yesterday for a reason... this question is a better fit there. You will be better served **asking** these questions on that site in the first place.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on ELU - it's an obscure point about typography, not relevant to the needs of English learners.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is that if you hyphenate a word, you should hyphenate between syllables.

But another common rule is to not break a word so that either line contains only one or two letters. Usually, if you have room for a hyphen you have room for one letter and maybe two. But this is not a universal rule, so it's not shocking if one source mentions it and another doesn't.

Comment: check out the other question here and you will see that it's maybe a bit more complex than that.... http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/327686/hyphenating-process-in-the-meaning-series-of-actions-in-ame?noredirect=1#comment747195_327686

Comment: @JavaLatte More complex in what way? I read that other question. Are there cases that are not cut and dried? Sure. I'd say the ambiguity is over where to put syllable breaks. If you want to say that the hyphenation is occurring at someplace different from the syllable breaks, while that assumes you can definitively state where the syllable breaks are.

Comment: One example: The syllables are hy-phe-'na-tion /hʌɪfəˈneɪʃ(ə)n/ with /ˈneɪ/ as the stressed syllable, but the hyphens are hy-phen-ation because hyphen is a word and -ation is a suffix.